# SQL Server and Table-Valued User-Defined Function optimizations

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

If I have an UDF that returns a table, with thousands of rows, but I just want a particular row from that rowset, will SQL Server be able to handle this effciently?

```
DECLARE @pID int; --...
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTableUDF(@pID)
WHERE SomeColumn BETWEEN 1 AND 2 OR SomeOtherColumn LIKE 'this_pattern&'
```

To what extent is the query optimizer capable of reasoning about this type of query?

How are Table-Valued UDFs different from traidtional views if they take no parameters?

Any gotchas I should know about?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you pass in the ID that you require as a parameter rather query the entire table?

Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyTableUDF(@ID int)
RETURNS @myTable TABLE 
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    FirstName nvarchar(50) NULL, 
    LastName nvarchar(50) NULL
)
as begin

Insert Into @myTable (ID, FirstName, LastName)
Select ID, FirstName, LastName
From Users
Where ID = @ID


return

end
go

Select * From MyTableUDF(1)
```

For this scenario, it would be a far better approach.

EDIT:

Ok well as you're using a Table UDF rather than a view I will assume that it a multi statement table UDF rather than an inline.  I am pretty sure that the performance won't be affected by using the UDF in this way.

The performance will really be hit if you used the UDF in a `Select` statement or `Where` clause. This is because the UDF will be called for each row returned from the table. 
e.g `Select col1, col2, dbo.MyUDF(col3) From MyTable`

or

```
Select col1, col2 from dbo.MyTable Where dbo.MyUDF(col3) != 1
```

So if you `MyTable` contained 100,000 rows, your UDF will be called 100,000 times.  If the UDF takes 5 seconds to execute that is where you will run in to issues.

As far as I can make out you don't intend on using the UDF in this manner.

Comment: yes, but that's not an answer to my question. Of course, if it's just a view then I woudn't need an UDF in the first place. There's plenty of search criterias on the return table value which can't or doesn't make sense as parameters. Those have to be handled efficently.

Comment: I made some changes to the example to better illustrate my problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The idea of UDFs is to provide a parameterized view of data, 'tis it not?

Comment: Inline Table UDF's are similar to using a view, however, multi statement UDF's allow you to perform far more logic than traditional views. UDF can be used for far more uses than views, for example UDF's can be used recursively.